# Form border style none was closed while minimized to tray will not restore

Tags: vb.net, forms, restore, taskbar, minimize

Created a form in VB.net 2013 with

```
Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
```

And a button with

```
Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Minimized
```

The issue is, if the User closes the form while the form was minimized to the taskbar, when you start the program back up again... you can see the program in the taskbar, but clicking on the taskbar icon for the program does nothing... clicking on the notification tray icon for the program does nothing...  EVEN if the notification tray icon is set to

```
Form.Show
Form.Activate
Form.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Normal
```

I have tried forcing the form to refresh.

I have tried forcing the form to redraw itself at the initial size.

The only thing that works to show it again after this defunct state is to put

```
Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized
```

in the form_load event, then let the form load, stop debugging, and then comment out the line again so the form goes back to how it is suppose to be.

Am I missing something?

Also, hovering over the taskbar icon for the program shows the full form in peek... so it does appear to be loaded, just not in the state that it should be in.

Comment: You must be writing the FormWindowState or the location and size to disk somewhere when you close the form.

Comment: Omg, yes, Been a frustrating day and I should have seen that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you are writing the WindowState or the location and size properties when you close the form.

If saving the location and size, make sure to first check the WindowState property:

```
If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
  '// save your form size and location
End If
```

Comment: Yes, I should have done that from the start, but when you are trying to code multiple programs at the same time... I tend to forget what I was doing last sometimes.